# Produce points out of csv dataset in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I've got a csv file like this:

```
Title, Longitude, Latitude
Photo1, 77.94, 20.665
Photo2, 62.508, 36.548
Photo3, 39.64, 52.547
Photo4, 39.6435, 52.77
Photo5, 70.642, 20.547
```

Longitude and Latitude are the coordinates where each photo was taken. Now, I need to produce points out of the file and then cluster them with different algorithms.

I tried this:

```
T = readtable('testdata.csv','Format','%s%f%f')

x = T(:, 2);
y = T(:, 3);

lon=[x,0];
lat=[0,y];

data = [lon lat];
```

using lon, lat in scatter function, but as it seems I'm completely wrong. If somebody could help me, it would be great. Sorry for the silly question, but I'm completely new to matlab.

Comment: If `T` holds the table from the file, then isn't `data = T(2:end, 2:3)` what you want?

Comment: One more thing - `lon = [x,0];` should give you an error, as `x` is a column vector and the dimensions of `x` and `0` do not match.

Comment: Thanks for help! I changed x = T(:, 2); and y = T(:, 3); to x = T{:, 2}; and y = T{:, 3}; and my plot seems all right now. I know lon = [x,0]; is completely wrong, but I used it as a last try, I just deleted these two lines.  data = T(2:end, 2:3) is what I want, but for some reason it doesn't work when I pass data as argument in the clustering functions.

Answer (score 0):

The `scatter` function expects two vectors as the point coordinates. Thus, I think what you need is:

```
scatter(x, y);
```

where `x` and `y` are defined as in the question.

Comment: I' ve changed scatter function, my plot is correct now, but then I need to compute a kernel distance from these points, that's why I need data array which is data = T(2:end, 2:3) as you said. But, when I'm passing data as argument in kernel function I get an error.

Comment: @simpleman91 - you should update your question with the exact line that makes you problems (what is this kernel function and how do you call it). Right now, there is not enough information in the question.

Comment: and while we're at it - welcome to SO and make sure you read the FAQ.

Comment: sorry you are right. I didn't update the question, because I thought that what caused the error was only this part of code and the way I wrote these lines, that's why I asked for the right way to write them. I realized the real problem later. I found the mistake in the rest of the code and corrected it, It's ok now. Thank you a lot for the help.